# xcode: color icons appear as grey squares in storyboard

Tags: xcode, icons, png, uibarbuttonitem

When I add a black and white or grey and white image to an imageset in xcode and I then select it from the tabbed button Bar Item section, it appears in the storyboard with no issues.  But when I do the same for a color image, it appears as a grey square in the storyboard.

Steps: (grey)
1. Import png (or other image file) into Prepo.  
Result: Prepo creates batch of images.
2. Drag image from Finder into 1x and 2x portions of "third" imageset.  
Result: Icon image appears in imageset tab with no problems.
[image]
3. Switch to storyboard. Select "third" imageset from Bar Item section of storyboard. 
Result: Icon appears in storyboard on relevant view controller.
[image]

Steps: (color)
1. Import png (or other image file) into Prepo.  
Result: Prepo creates batch of images.
2. Drag image from Finder into 1x and 2x portions of "second" imageset.  
Result: Icon image appears in imageset tab with no problems.
[image]

3. Switch to storyboard. Select "second" imageset from Bar Item section of storyboard. 
Result: Icon does NOT appear in storyboard on relevant view controller.  Covering Bar item is a grey rectangle.
[image]

Comment: You have enough reputation to put images into your questions now.  Why not edit your question to show what you are talking about.  And while we are on the subject, can you open the inspector for the bar item and show what image it is set to display?

Comment: Sorry about that - never think to add images.  I have added images with inspector open as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you set UITabBarItems' image property it automatically sets the render mode of the image to template. If you want to use a full color image as a tabbar item image you should explicitly set the render mode of the image to `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`. You can set this in a .xcassets folder by selecting the image, opening the right pane, and setting render as "Original Image".

[image]

Right now the tabbar is only looking at the alpha value of the image and tinting it gray. For more information you can look at the [UIKit User Interface Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITabBar.html)